# Send logs to syslog

Tags: fiware-orion

I need to send ContxtBroker log to syslog but the other method I could find is via imfile, which is very inaccurate in timing.

Is there any way for sending ContextBroker logs directly to syslog?

Answer (score 0):

The orion context broker only outputs its log information to its log file (which defaults at /tmp/contextBroker.log), and currently we don't have any intention of changing this behavior, sorry.

You could always implement a process that reads from the log file, parses the log contents and forwards the log message to syslog. Doesn't seem too difficult ...